# Full time notation NL

Tags: php, magento, time

My time in my code is displayed as: 2014-11-28 00:00:00

But i want it to be displayed as: Vrijdag 28 November 2014 ( DUTCH LANGUAGE )

I use just the php time code

```
$specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
```

I use it in magento.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: time() returns a unix time stamp - an integer. Perhaps you want http://php.net/date or http://php.net/strftime ?

Comment: See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: :'), sorry i already use that

Comment: Already used what? There are multiple links here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

```
date('l d F Y H:i:s);
```

Comment: @ThijsKempers You may want to avoid this kind of comment when you're asking for people's freely provided help and time.